# Save data to firebase realtime database if OTP verification is done

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-router

```
enter code here



Submit=e=>{

      e.preventDefault();
        let data="";
      this.setUpRecaptcha();
      // window.alert("Appointment Done Successfully at time "+this.state.curTime+" ! Go to the home page");
      var phoneNumber = this.state.contact;
      console.log(phoneNumber)
      var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
          .then(function (confirmationResult) {
            // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
            // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            var code = window.prompt("enter OTP")
            confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
              // User signed in successfully.
              var user = result.user;    
              alert("OTP is verified!!!");
              this.data="doneit";
              // ...
            }).catch(function (error) {
              // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
              // ...
              alert("OTP verification failed");
            });
          }).catch(function (error) {
            // Error; SMS not sent
            // ...
            alert("cann't send OTP use another Contact number")
          });

//Data storage code
          if(this.data=='doneit'){
            firebase.database().ref("appoinment").push(
              {
                name:this.state.name,
                email:this.state.email,
                contact:this.state.contact,
                age:this.state.age,
                gender:this.state.gender,
                Appointdate:this.state.Appointdate,
                Description:this.state.Description,
                date:this.state.curTime
              }
            );
            alert(" Data saved successfully");
            window.location.reload(false);
          }
          else{
            alert("failed");
          }


    };
```

My code is as shown above. I want execution in such a way that if after submitting form Submit() will be called. Then it will check for OTP verification. If it is successful then only data will be stored at firebase realtime database

1. List item

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the logic to save the data after the confirmation promise:

```
Submit=e=>{

      e.preventDefault();
        let data="";
      this.setUpRecaptcha();
      // window.alert("Appointment Done Successfully at time "+this.state.curTime+" ! Go to the home page");
      var phoneNumber = this.state.contact;
      console.log(phoneNumber)
      var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
          .then(function (confirmationResult) {
            // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
            // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            var code = window.prompt("enter OTP")
            confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
              // User signed in successfully.
              var user = result.user;    
              alert("OTP is verified!!!");
              this.data="doneit";

                 firebase.database().ref("appoinment").push({
                   name:this.state.name,
                   email:this.state.email,
                   contact:this.state.contact,
                   age:this.state.age,
                   gender:this.state.gender,
                   Appointdate:this.state.Appointdate,
                   Description:this.state.Description,
                   date:this.state.curTime
                });
               alert(" Data saved successfully");
               window.location.reload(false);


              // ...
            }).catch(function (error) {
              // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
              // ...
              alert("OTP verification failed");
            });
          }).catch(function (error) {
            // Error; SMS not sent
            // ...
            alert("cann't send OTP use another Contact number")
          });  

    };
```

Comment: I already did it. But when I did this it sends me OTP but at the time of confirmation it alert me as "OTP verification failed". Means confirmationResult.confirm(code) doesn't work fine although I entered correct OTP. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try to console.log() the error that you are catching? It might contain more information what is going wrong.

Comment: When I try console.log() it shows "Uncaught (in promise) null". But First, it alerts me "OTP is verified!!!" and then alert me as "OTP verification failed".

Comment: I tried some different ways. But whenever I write any logic inside                                  
 " confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) " this block it gives me an error and alert me as "OTP verification failed". Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I gave you answer to the question that was asked in the title and in the description. You should create different question for the firebase problem.